# Is the solution of a stationary Fokker-Planck equation the Boltzmann's distribution?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

I've seen that if we consider a stationary closed system such that $\partial_x J=0$, so that $J=const.$ and, since it must vanish at infinity, $J=0$, the solution of the Fokker-Planck equation $\partial_t\rho=-\mu\partial_x \rho f+D\partial^2_x \rho$ is the Boltzmann distribution $\rho(x)=\rho(0)e^{-\frac{\mu}{D}[V(x)-V(0)]}$ with $f=-\partial_x V$.

$\rho(x)$ is the probability of finding a particle in the position $x$, $f$ is an external force and $D$ is the diffusion coefficient.

Now what I don't understand is how this function can be a Boltzmann distribution, it seems to me a marginalized Boltzmann distribution since this last one is the probability of a certain configuration and not the probability of having a particle in the position $x$.

Comment: where have you "seen" this and what is the $t$ dependence of $\rho$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation#Recovering_Boltzmann_statistics